# Logging in to a website using my gmail account gives away my location but I can access the trail content without logging in. How?

Tags: authentication, vpn

When I use a VPN (Tunnel Bear) to India from USA and access Hotstar.com it takes me to the Indian version of the website. I can access and watch the trail streams offered but when I log in to the website it says the content isn’t available in my region. How?!

So basically without logging in to the website I can access all the Indian content, but as soon as I log in I can’t access them anymore.
How is me logging into the website with my gmail account give my location to them?!

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to help here. It can be anything from browser cookies cache before you turn on the VPN,  your SSO info leak,etc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they have somehow associated your account with a location outside of India. This can have happened in any number of ways:

- Perhaps you provided location information on sign up.
- Perhaps they have observed that your account is usually geolocated in a specific region, and tied that to the account permanently.
- I don't know what information Google gives away to sites that uses their SSO, but that could at least in theory be a third possibility.

Comment: Maybe he logged in the first time without the VPN, and the website is remembering that for further logins with the same email address.

Comment: @Ángel Yeah, that is what I am trying to say in the second bullet point.